# Duplicated block of Code in Sonar for import statements in Java

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5, sonarqube-web

In Sonar 4.5.6 (with default settings) I am seeing `Duplicated Blocks` message as

[image]

My java code for which I am getting the message is like below:-

```
package com.jabong.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.endpoints;

import com.jabong.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request.UpdateOrderStatusReadyShipRequest;

public class UpdateOrderReadyShipEndPoint extends BaseOrderEndPoint {
    private final static String API_NAME = "setStatusToReadyToShip";

    @Override
    public String getSourceEndPoint() {
    return new StringBuilder("direct:").append(API_NAME).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDestinationEndPoint() {
    return new StringBuilder("bean:orderHelper?method=").append(API_NAME).toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getName() {
    return API_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getApiInputClassName() {
    return UpdateOrderStatusReadyShipRequest.class.getName();
    }
}
```

`UpdateOrderStatusReadyShipRequest` also does not import `UpdateOrderReadyShipEndPoint`

```
package com.jabong.orchestratorservice.adapter.order.request;

public class UpdateOrderStatusReadyShipRequest extends BaseOrderRequest {
```

Can some let me know what does this mean?

Comment: Does the other class import this one?

Comment: No it does not import.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The Duplicate Blocks rule raises issues at the file level. So it's not trying to tell you that your import statement is duplicated, but that somewhere in the file is a duplicate block. If you'll scroll down, you should see a vertical yellow/orange bar in the left margin. It marks the duplicate block. Click on the bar to get details of where the block is duplicated.

**EDIT** In more recent versions the duplication marker is brown or gray.

Comment: I had same issue on my project. Abstract class implemented with two other classes with same overrides. Sonar issued this as same block. But actually it was not. Anyway I get rid of it by replacing method order in one of that classes. Funny, isn't it? :)

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team Where Can I find the logic of this rule common-java:DuplicatedBlocks ?

Comment: It's in SonarQube itself

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team .Would be quite interesting to know how this works.This rule is in sonarqube and rest of the rules starting with squid-xxxx are in sonar-java.Is Sonar using some external library to check code duplication?

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team Thank you for the hint ,I have figured out  how copy code is working.

Comment: what to do in case of similar type of private variables and there getter/setter which are marked as duplicate blocks?

Answer (score 24):

You have to look (scroll down) your code. There will be a duplication marker in brown/gray like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, We could locate the duplicate block of code and the lines as mentioned clearly by you in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks you saved my day. The yellow background on code lines is really misleading.

Comment: Woah ! thanks man Sonarqube needs to do better at documentation. You saved the day !

Comment: Thanks Carlos, your screenshot is a savior. I was scrolling mindlessly, and this gray marker wasn't catching my attention.